# JUnit string compare fails for emoji

Tags: java, unicode, junit, emoji

I'm getting a test failure that shows

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :‍⚕‍♂️️
Actual   :‍⚕️‍♂️
```

Those two strings look the same to me! What am I missing here? I'm thinking the console is hiding some characters like maybe a zero width joiner?

Here's my code. I have other tests using , , and ‍⚕️. It only fails with ‍⚕️‍♂️

```
class Emoji {
    static String unicodeStringFromCodePointStrings(String[] codePointStrings) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String codePointString : codePointStrings) {
            codePointString = codePointString.replace("U+","");
            int codePoint = Integer.parseInt(codePointString, 16);
            char[] chars = Character.toChars(codePoint);
            sb.append(new String(chars));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}

public class EmojiTest {
    @Test
    public void testMultipleCompoundEmoji() {
        String[] input = "U+1F469 U+200D U+2695 U+FE0F U+1F9D8 U+200D U+2642 U+FE0F".split(" ");
        String output = Emoji.unicodeStringFromCodePointStrings(input);
        assertEquals("‍⚕‍♂️️", output);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first (expected) is

`\u1F469\u200D\u2695\u1F9D8\u200D\u2642\uFE0F\uFE0F`

The second (actual) is

`\u1F469\u200D\u2695\uFE0F\u1F9D8\u200D\u2642\uFE0F`

As you can see, in the expected value, both `U+FE0F` characters are at the end.

They might *look* the same, but they are not the same `String` values.

The difference was easy to see once you copy/paste the text into a UTF-8 converter, e.g. http://www.endmemo.com/unicode/unicodeconverter.php

Comment: Very strange, I just erased it and typed again and now the test passes. The second (actual) is correct. Any idea how that \uFE0F could have moved around in the string literal? The expected value now shows ⚕after the ‍⚕️